# Shared partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views

What would be the best way to display on home page (HomeController, view Index) two last news from other model (News)?

I've created partial view in shared views directory, there is how it looks like:

```
   @model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.News>

     @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.IsActive ==
     true).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).Take(2))  {
         <li>
             @Html.ActionLink(item.DateCreated.ToString(), "Details", "News", new { id = item.NewsId})
             <p>@item.Content</p>
         </li>
 }
```

but this way I'm getting error:

```
 An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
 System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Model is not null, there are exactly two "active" records in my db, index file for this model is also correct, but I don't have any idea how to render this partial to my index homepage... (now I have in Index.cshtml view for HomeController      `@Html.Partial("_LatestNews")`)

Thanks for advance for any help.

Comment: Do I need some action to render such a partial view?

Comment: the place from where u r calling , model type of that must be like MyApp.Models.News chk

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to pass the model into the partial, like such;

@Html.Partial("_LatestNews", Model.News))

Answer (score 0):

Your partial view is expecting IEnumerable which you missed to pass, it should have something like this.

```
@Html.Partial("_LatestNews", new IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.News>)
```

**However, I would do rather following in this case.**

**Layout View Page**

### Latest News

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#content").html("Loading...");
        //Use setTimeout if you want to keep update or call LoadPartialView() directly.
        setTimeout(function () { LoadPartialView(); }, 5000);
    });
    function LoadPartialView() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNews", "Home")',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").empty();
                $("#content").html(data);
                $("#content").fadeIn('slow');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#content").empty();
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetNews()
    {
        List<MyApp.Models.News> model = db.GetNews();

        return PartialView("_LatestNews", model);
    }
```